# Scanner reading large file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am playing around with the Scanner class for learning purposes and i use it to read a very large file (60.000 lines aprox) without using the Reader class , and it stops reading after approximately 400 lines. Do i have to use a Bufferedreader inside the Scanner's constructor or the problem is something else? I want to know why this is happening. Thanks.
My code is the usual code to output all the lines.

```
File file1 = new File("file1");
Scanner in= new Scanner(file1);
while  (scan.hasNextLine()  ) {
String str = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Any exception after your 400 lines ? Did you check memory consumption?

Comment: on large files i recommend you to use buffered classes.. because difference in performance is really huge..

Comment: It may be the console not outputting all the lines and truncating some. Are you using BlueJ?

Comment: No,i'm using Eclipse.

Comment: I experienced the same thing today with a file with 25000 lines. I switched to BufferedReader and that worked perfect. And I have a 64-bit machine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is usually more common on 64 bit machines or with files having size more than 1-2 GB and does not have anything to do with heap space. Switch to BufferedReader it should work fine,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
String line = "";
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: hm...actually my machine is a 64 bit,is that the main reason?

Comment: This is caused mostly due to JVM implementation on your machine.

Answer (score 6):

I just experienced this very problem. It seems that it works just by changing the scanner construction. Replace this:

```
File file1 = new File("file1");
Scanner in= new Scanner(file1);
```

with this:

```
FileReader file1 = new FileReader("file1");
Scanner in= new Scanner(file1);
```

Maybe the problem appears when you build your scanner from a file without the system knowing that it is a text file.

Comment: work for me. i'm curious why this happen. java has so many strange behavior..