# Issue with Scanner hasNextLine() but resolved with BufferedReader readLine()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have a file with 84000 lines in it.

My goal is to add each one of these lines to a `String` `ArrayList`. For some reason, it does not work using `Scanner`'s `hasNextLine()`, but does work with `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()`. The `Scanner` version stops about 1/5 of the way through the file. The `BufferedReader` version correctly goes to the end. There is nothing special about line 17132. It's a normal line like every other line.

For example, I have the following:

```
File file = new File("wordlist.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList <String> ();
ArrayList <String> al2 = new ArrayList <String> ();

String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null)
{
    al.add(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}

while (s.hasNextLine())
    al2.add(s.nextLine());

System.out.println(al.size());
System.out.println(al2.size());
```

Here, the first print statement evaluates to 84095 (correct) and the second to 17132 (incorrect). Can anyone provide some insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer here, I think this is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330695/java-scanner-not-going-through-entire-file

Comment: Have you tried to read a different file so you can be sure it isn't the file what causes this?

Comment: There a more questions to that problem on SO. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813760/scanner-reading-large-file#19813956

Comment: So to: it works on my home computer but does not work on my work computer. Same files. So strange. We should transition to Python.